# Why does my function not get Called inside click event of google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, google-maps, google-api

I am not sure what is the concept behind this problem, may be its a closure or something other. I have no clue as to why this function can't execute. Looks to me it executes but my browser just turns blank. Not sure whats happening.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click', function searchComplete() {  

    function outside() {

        google.load('search', '1');
        var newsSearch;   
        function onLoad() { 
            // Create a News Search instance.
            newsSearch = new google.search.NewsSearch();

            // Set searchComplete as the callback function when a search is 
            // complete.  The newsSearch object will have results in it.
            newsSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, searchComplete, null);

            // Specify search quer(ies)
            newsSearch.execute('Obama');

            // Include the required Google branding
            google.search.Search.getBranding('branding');
        }

        // Set a callback to call your code when the page loads
        google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
    }

    outside();
});
```

I have also set up a JSFIDDLE:

[**http://jsfiddle.net/L9MDu/3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9MDu/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in assuming that `onload()` is not being called?

From what I can gather, `setOnLoadCallback` functions similar to a `DOMReady` ready state, and not a callback for a library loaded dynamically via `google.load()`.

I tried the following, which caused the entire thing to loop and alert indefinitely. Perhaps this is desired?

```
google.load('search', '1', {
    callback: function() {
        onLoad();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, I did something like what you suggested. but I am still not able to access onLoad function. Can you please check this  On marker drag end, It will say onLoad is not defined. http://jsfiddle.net/gWjmh/2/ Please help